# Docker Certificate Unknow Issue on OpenSuSE

Tags: docker, certificate, opensuse

I am trying to use docker push on my **opensuse 15.1** server. And the target repository is a private repository with https protocol.
**docker version: 18.09.6.**
I tried to get the certificate by

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect myurl.com:443 2>/dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > dockerCA.crt
```

I put it at following path:

```
/usr/share/pki/trust/anchors/
/etc/pki/trust/anchors/
/etc/docker/certs.d/myurl.com/
```

and run

```
update-ca-certificates
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker.service
```

After done all things above, the docker push still failed with certificate validate failed. Is there anyone know what's the problem and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: AFAIK unless the certificate is self-signed it will be validated. What you need is the "root" certificate for the authority that issued the repo certificate (likely some corporate certificate)